# Is it possible to install PowerShell 3 on a Windows Server 2003 or 2003 R2?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server-2003, powershell-3.0

On a [Windows Server 2003](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2003) rig (which already has .NET 4 but no 4.5 on it) that is to be expired before the end of the year, I'd like to run a few [PowerShell 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell#PowerShell_3.0) scripts on a scheduled base as the scripts depend on functionality introduced in PowerShell 3.

There are not many useful hits in the [search I tried](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22powershell%203%22%20%22windows%20server%202003%22) as they give mixed information: [Some indicate](http://www.everonit.com/techtips/techtips/how-to-installconfigure-powershell-3-0-in-windows-7-sp1/) it [is possible](http://www.invoke-ir.com/2013/07/powershell-intro.html) but [others](http://powershell.org/wp/tag/windows-server-2008-r2/) indicate [impossible](http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2012/09/05/powershell-3-0-is-available-for-downlevel-systems/) and it certainly is [not in the official downloads](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34595).

So:

1. Are there workarounds to install PowerShell 3 on Windows Server 2003?
2. If not, where should I look for replacement [Cmdlets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell#Cmdlets) that are unique to PowerShell 3 like [Invoke-RestMethod](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849971.aspx), [ConvertTo-Json](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849898.aspx), [ConvertFrom-Json](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849898.aspx) or [Invoke-WebRequest](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849901.aspx)?

Comment: Have you simply tried installing it?

Comment: @EBGreen which .MSU file would you suggest, and how should I install it on Windows Server 2003?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. No.
2. I would use Poshcode/ Jaykul modules:

   - [JSON](http://poshcode.org/2930)
   - [REST](http://poshcode.org/2097)

Comment: Thanks. 1 wasn't what I hoped for, but the Poshcode looks promising (well, the ones not requiring too many assemblies). I might go for the built-in .NET Object though. Need to give this some thinking, as depending on the amount of time, I might migrate the server to a more modern Window as well.

Comment: I've investigating how much work it will be to migrate the machine, as opposed to adapting the scripts with Poshcode/Jaykul modules (of which many have external dependencies that I'd need to check first). It's about the same order of magnitude, so I'll be migrating the machine earlier. In the mean time, a different machine will run the scripts and access the required data over a network share.